# ggplot2 and Shiny conditional aesthetics based on selectInput?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I've built a shiny dashboard and part of it will allow people to produce graphs that are relevant to their geographic area. Areas will be listed in the sidebar as a selectInput with the areas plotted on the graph, however, if they select England I want this to have different aesthetics, in particular be a thicker line, so that it stands out. All other areas should be the same thickness but should still be different colours so they can be told apart. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious!

```
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarid", 
                               menuItem("Graphs", tabName = "graphs", icon = icon("chart-line")),
                               conditionalPanel(
                                 'input.sidebarid == "graphs"',
                                 selectInput("area", "Area",
                                             c("England", "Bolton","Bury","Manchester","Oldham", "Rochdale", "Salford","Stockport","Tameside","Trafford","Wigan"),
                                             multiple = T, selected = "Manchester")
                               )
                   )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    ## Maps Tab, core dashboard
      tabItem(
        tabName = "graphs",
        fluidRow(
          width = "100%",
          plotOutput("chart"),
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- 
  
  function(input,output, session){
    
    area <- reactive({
      NCMPRec_time %>% filter(AreaName %in% input$area)
    })
    
    output$chart <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(area(), aes(x=Timeperiod, y=Value, group = AreaName)) +
        geom_line(aes(color = AreaName)) +
        geom_point(aes(color = AreaName)) +
        labs(x = "Time", y = "Percent", col="Area") +
        theme_classic() +
        scale_colour_branded()
    })
    

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the line size dependent on `input$area`:

```
output$chart <- renderPlot({
      if (input$area == "England") {
        line_size <- 1
      } else {
        line_size <- 0.5
      }
      
      ggplot(area(), aes(x=Timeperiod, y=Value, group = AreaName)) +
        geom_line(aes(color = AreaName), size = line_size) +
        geom_point(aes(color = AreaName)) +
        labs(x = "Time", y = "Percent", col="Area") +
        theme_classic() +
        scale_colour_branded()
    })
```